# Convert a CSS string to CSSStyleDeclaration

Tags: javascript, css

Getting a CSS string from a CSSStyleDeclaration is made with `el.style.cssText`, but how can I convert a string, e.g. `width:20px; height:20px; background:lime;` to a CSSStyleDeclaration object?

My final goal is to merge two CSS declarations, one coming from `el.style` the other as a string. I thought it was easier to convert both as CSSStyleDeclaration objects to merge it. Let me know if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const styles = "width:20px; height:20px; background:lime;"

const el = document.createElement('div');

el.style.cssText = styles;

const cssStyleDeclaration = el.style;
```